# Is it possible to add "no follow" tags to html button in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Is it possible to add `rel="nofollow"` to an html button using the below code in WordPress.

```
<input type="button" 
     onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com/');return false;" 
     value="TEXT" />
```

I am using above code for displaying external links and want to add `rel="nofollow"` to those external links.

If there is anything better than above please let me know.

Now I know we can make button using a tag but on mouse hover it still display the URL of a tag , also it allows text selection of the button which I want to avoid [these are not the case in the above code I posted]

Comment: Why not `<a href='http://www.example.com/' target='_blank' rel='nofollow'>TEXT</a>`?

Comment: `rel='nofollow'` is not a valid attribute for `<input>`. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

you can do like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
<input type="button" value="TEXT" /></a>
```

instead of:

```
<input type="button" 
 onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com/');return false;" 
 value="TEXT" />
```